# How Do I use ClipboardJS to copy the contents of all Input tags in HTML?

Tags: clipboard.js

So I am currently building a macro for Shortcuts App by Apple. As I am Building this HTML inside I ran across an Issue, I for some reason can’t figure how to copy text using Clipboard.js

https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/435b6df7895c4241804f5487ac795942

The Following code is supports Cliboard.JS but Dosen’t actually work

What I want to do is copy all the text fields of Input Tags ( the ones with Id “test” and “test2”) to clipboard. And If possible as a JSON or XML file.

Assume, `<script type="text/javascript">clipboard.js</script>
<script type="text/javascript">JQuery</script>`
This lines contains the library for both jquery and clipboard.js

Thanks,

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>constructor-nodelist</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script type="text/javascript">clipboard.js</script>
<script type="text/javascript">JQuery</script>
<body>
    <!-- 1. Define some markup -->
    <input id="test" type="text">
<input id="test2" type="text">
    <button data-clipboard-target="textarea">Copy</button>

    <!-- 3. Instantiate clipboard by passing a list of HTML elements -->
    <script>
 //document.write(ClipboardJS.isSupported());
    new ClipboardJS('.btn', {
    text: function(trigger) {
         var a = document.getElementById('#test').value;
        var b = document.querySelector('#test2').value;
        var c = a+b;
        return c;
    }
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```